# Collection Dependency Property not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF User Control representing a Circular Gauge with some properties in it. When I Directly use it in my application everything works just fine but when I load it in Expression Blend in order to test its properties and simulate the expected animations it works expect collection dependency  properties. The problem is when I use Expression Blend to add some item to the collection property 
The “SetValue” is not called! What am I doing wrong?

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RangesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Ranges ", typeof(CircularRangeInfoList), typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new CircularRangeInfoList()));

    [Category("Test Collection")]
    public CircularRangeInfoList Ranges
    {
        get { return (CircularRangeInfoList)GetValue(RangesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RangesProperty, value); }
    }
public class CircularRangeInfoList : ObservableCollection<CircularRangeInfo>
{
    public CircularRangeInfoList()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are not setting the property, you are altering the collection (to which the property is already set). If you need to watch for changes in the collection, then you should add a handler for the CollectionChanged event.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845405/how-to-propertly-use-coercevaluecallback-in-a-custom-wpf-usercontrol/6845701#6845701) for more information.

Comment: well I'm 
Interested in receiving the notification outside the collection I mean inside my UserControl1. Such that I already set the property and it worked but only once… What do you mean by I’m altering my collection and where?

Comment: @rsleiman - You said "add some item to the collection", that means you are altering the collection (i.e. adding an item, removing an item, moving an item, or replacing an item). If you want to know when the collection changes, you must use CollectionChanged. That is different that when the property changes.

Comment: Oh I see, but yes I later changed the code that instantiates my custom list to support the CollectionChanged event. It seems to work fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you register your dependency property, [specify a static property changed callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557299.aspx). This will be invoked when your dependency property is changed. Within this callback delegate, you should attach an event handler to the [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged.aspx) event of your custom collection.